# multiple file upload with angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, file-upload

I am trying to build a form in Angular 6 that offers a file selection box that allows the user to select multiple files (Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjummp).

The Template looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input id="files" formControlName="files" type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple (change)="onFilesChanged($event)"/>
</form>
```

I am building the form in TypeScript like this:

```
  public form = new FormGroup({
    files: new FormControl('')
  });

  public onFilesChanged(event: any): void {
    console.log(event.target.files);
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

Now, in the `onFilesChanged` Handler, the selected files can be correctly retrieved from the event by accessing `event.target.files` (obviously), but printing the form value only prints one file. I have been trying a number of ways using `FormArray` as well, but had no luck so far.

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: Tomorrow I publish the answer, now I have to sleep after breaking my head solving this.

Comment: @nicogaldo: any chance you could share your solution with us?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below is example that how I achieved multiple photo upload input file through angular reactive forms.

```
public demoForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.demoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       text_input: ['', Validators.required],
       photos: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
}

// We will create multiple form controls inside defined form controls photos.
createItem(data): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group(data);
}

//Help to get all photos controls as form array.
get photos(): FormArray {
    return this.demoForm.get('photos') as FormArray;
};

detectFiles(event) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
        for (let file of files) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                this.photos.push(this.createItem({
                    file,
                    url: e.target.result  //Base64 string for preview image
                }));
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
}
```

In component html

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">

<div class="images-preview mt-2" *ngIf="photos.length">
    <div formArrayName="photos" *ngFor="let photo of photos.controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <img [src]="photo.controls.url.value" class="card-img-top" alt="Image Preview">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can avoid html if you do not want to show preview. On submit of form you will be get values like below.

```
{
    text_input: "",
    photos: [
       {
           file: <File Object>,
           url: <Base64 String here>
       },
       {
           file: <File Object>,
           url: <Base64 String here>
       },
       ....
    ] 
}
```

**Edit**
Here is working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-tirjjg)

I hope it will helps you and also other peoples.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I cannot confirm that this answer is working at the moment, but I'll accept in anyways and will undo in case it's not working. Again: many thanks!

Comment: not the perfect solution! but it works in some cases

Comment: @sadeghhp Can you perhaps provide issue so I can correct it.

Comment: at backend i got `file:{}` instead of `file: <File Object>`

Comment: @suhailvs Make sure you send a correct request because of photos array that i created here to print file object and base64 both so you might need to array with only [<File Object>, <File Object>, <File Object>, ...]   and that should send in multipart form data request.